# Solving a PDE with non-homogenous boundary conditions

Tags: sequences-and-series, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, inner-products

To give some background if you don't want to read every step in the solution, essentially I want to find the Fourier coefficients to solve the PDE. However, one of the coefficients don't vanish when I plug in my second boundary condition, something I'm not familiar with from before. If you want, you can go down and read what I mean if you are not interested in seeing my steps along the way. I'll present them anyway.

I'm currently trying to solve this pde (two-dimensional):

$$ \Delta u = y$$

for $(x,y) \in [0,2] \times [0,1]$ with boundary conditions $u(x,0) = u(x,1) = 0$ and $u(0,y) = y-y^3$ and $u(2,y) = 0$.

Since we have an inhomogenous pde, we will try to find a steady state at first. Let's choose this to be only dependent in $y$, $S(y)$. We want it to satisfy the PDE and the boundary conditions, so $S(0) = S(1) = 0$. Therefore

$$S''(y) = y \Rightarrow S(y) = 1/6(y^3-y)$$

for our given boundary conditions. We now seek a solution on the form $u(x,y) = n(x,y) + S(x,y)$ where $n$ solves the PDE:

$$ \Delta n = 0$$

and with the same boundary conditions in $y$, since they don't change from our steady-state solution. However, now we have that:

$$n(0,y) = y-y^3 - S(y) = 1/6(7y-5^3)$$

$$n(2,y) = -S(y) = -1/6(y^3-y)$$

By separating the variables for $n = X(x)Y(y)$ in the PDE we get:

$$X''/X = -Y''/Y = \mu$$

Solving for $Y$ first gives us the ODE: $Y'' + \mu Y = 0$ which for nonzero $\mu$ has a solution on the form $Y(y) := a \cos(\sqrt{\mu}y)  + b \sin(\sqrt{\mu}y)$. With our boundary conditions on $Y(0) = Y(1) = 0$, we have that $Y_n(y) = \sin(\pi n y)$ where $\sqrt{\mu_n} := \pi n$ satisfies the ODE in Y.

Solving the ODE in $X$ gives us:

$$X'' -\pi^2 n^2 X= 0$$

where $X(x) = a_n \cosh(\pi n x) + b_n \sinh(\pi n x)$, therefore the solution for $n$ can be written as a superposition:

$$n(x,y) := \sum_{n\geq 1} (a_n \cosh(\pi n x) + b_n \sinh(\pi n x)) \sin(\pi n y) $$

To find the coefficients $a_n$, use our boundary conditions. Namely:

$$n(0,y) =  \sum_{n\geq 1}a_n \sin(\pi n y) = 1/6(7y-5y^3)$$
so simply
$$ a_n := \frac{\langle 1/6(7y-5y^3), \sin(\pi n y) \rangle}{ || \sin(\pi n y)||^2} = \frac {2(15+\pi^2n^2)(-1)^{n-1}}{3\pi^2n^2}$$

But now I have a problem calculating $b_n$ since if we use the second boundary condition in $x$, namely $n(2,y) =  \sum_{n\geq 1} (a_n \cosh(2\pi n) + b_n \sinh(2\pi n)) \sin(\pi n y) = 1/6(y-y^3)$, the $a_n$ terms don't vanish.

Usually when I do this procedure for solving a PDE, the $a_n$ terms vanish so it becomes easier to calculate $b_n$. Now, this isn't the case, and I'm not familiar on how to move on from here. If you have any ideas, please share them. I tried moving the sum for $a_n$ to the right of the equation to isolate $b_n$ and use the hermitian scalar product as before, however, it just becomes a big mess where I have to calculate an infinite sum that I'm not familiar with.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tip: Don't name your index the same as your function. $a_n$ and $n(x, \ y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you did is correct. But I would like to rewrite the problem and point out the boundary conditions.

$$
\begin{align*}
\Delta n & = 0 \\
n(x, \ 0) & = 0 \\
n(x, \ 1) & = 0 \\
n(0, \ y) & = \color{red}{\dfrac{7y\left(1-y^2\right)}{6}} \\
n(2, \ y) & = \dfrac{y(1-y^2)}{6} \\
\end{align*}
$$

Doing separation of variables:

$$\begin{align*}n(x, \ y) & = X(x) \cdot Y(y) \\ X(x) & = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_{j} \cdot \cosh \left(j \pi x\right) + b_{j} \cdot \sinh \left(j \pi x\right)\\ Y(y) & = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \sin \left(j\pi y\right) \end{align*}$$

Applying the boundary conditions:

- For $x = 0$:

$$n(0, \ y) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \left( a_{j} \cdot \underbrace{\cosh \left(j \pi \cdot 0\right)}_{1} + b_{j} \cdot \underbrace{\sinh \left(j \pi \cdot 0\right)}_{0} \right)  \sin \left(j\pi y\right) = \dfrac{7y(1-y^2)}{6} \label{1}\tag{1}$$

- For $x = 2$:

$$n(2, \ y) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \underbrace{\left( a_{j} \cdot \cosh \left(2j \pi\right) + b_{j} \cdot \sinh \left(2j \pi\right) \right)}_{c_j}  \sin \left(j\pi y\right) = \dfrac{y(1-y^2)}{6} \label{2}\tag{2}$$

From \eqref{1} you can find $a_j$:

$$a_j = \left\langle \dfrac{7y(1-y^2)}{6}, \ \sin \left(j\pi y\right)\right\rangle\tag{3}\label{3}$$

From \eqref{2} you can find $c_{j}$:

$$c_j = \left\langle \dfrac{y(1-y^2)}{6}, \ \sin \left(j\pi y\right)\right\rangle\tag{4}\label{4}$$

With \eqref{3} and \eqref{4} you can find $b_j$:

$$b_{j} = \dfrac{c_j - a_{j} \cosh \left(2j\pi\right)}{\sinh \left(2j\pi\right)}$$

With the notation $\langle f, \ g\rangle$ is the inner product of two functions:

$$\langle f(y), \ g(y) \rangle = \int_{-1}^{1} f(y) \cdot g(y) \ dy $$
$$\left\langle \sin \left(i\pi y\right), \sin \left(j\pi y\right) \right\rangle = \delta_{ij} = \begin{cases}1 \ \ \ \text{if} \ i = j \\ 0 \ \ \ \text{else}\end{cases}$$

Comment: In your solution solve for the steady state at the end, why can't you start solving the pde with the steady state first, and then substract it away? That's what I'm familiar with at least.

Comment: @Tanamas I edited the answer. The first I did is the way I like to use: separate the boundary conditions from the "force". But the way you did, finding a function that satisfies in the middle and throwing the effects on the boundary conditions work as well.

Comment: Oh okay! I thought that the order matter so that's why I commented on that. Thank you for your time answering me! Now I understand :)